# Array .each() loop returning string instead of value in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

Sorry, this may be an easy one, but it has me stumped.  I'm trying to loop over this array and log out each value, but the script is logging out a string object.

```
propertiesToSanitize = ["title", "description", "place_name"]
$.each propertiesToSanitize, ->
  console.log this
```

which converts to jQuery as

```
var propertiesToSanitize;
propertiesToSanitize = ["title", "description", "place_name"];
$.each(propertiesToSanitize, function() {
  return console.log(this);
});
```

is returning:

```
String
  0: "t"
  1: "i"
  2: "t"
  3: "l"
  4: "e"
  length: 5
```

Any idea why it's returning this instead of just "title" or any other value?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If you just do `console.log(this + "")` or `console.log(this.toString())`, it'll give you the string primitive you're expecting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the index and the value for each iteration are provided as a parameter in the callback.

```
$.each(propertiesToSanitize, function(index,value) {
    console.log(index + ':' + value);
});
```

Comment: That seems to have done the trick! Couldn't really find that documentation anywhere.  Thanks for the help, mate.

Comment: @mlp.brooklyn actually, [there is a documentation for it](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because `this` is very complicated in JavaScript.  The `this` variable in a callback often references something deep inside the scope stack that you shouldn't rely on.  With [jQuery's `each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), "Javascript will always wrap the `this` value as an `Object` even if it is a simple string or number value", which is what you're seeing.

jQuery's `each` passes the value as second argument to your callback. In your JavaScript, you would probably want this:

```
$.each(propertiesToSanitize, function(idx, val) {
  return console.log(idx + ":" + val);
});
```

But note also CoffeeScript is very capable of looping over an array without jQuery's help:

```
for propName in propertiesToSanitize
  console.log propName
```

Comment: `this` can be relied upon to be the value of each item in an iteration using `$.each()`. The issue is that in non-strict mode, the string is provided as its String object wrapper instead of the primitive.